# Sweet alert doesn't send the Id of my element when submiting the form (ASP.Net core mvc)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I have a question regarding the use of sweet alert on Asp.net core 2.2 mvc. While trying to make an alert to confirm a post event on my controller `AdminUsersController`, the action returns an error because the requested id is `null`, but when I don't use sweet alert the event works perfect.

I'm trying to get this to work on Asp.net core 2.2 on Visual studio 2017 community, I've never had any problems before with crud operations regarding Id's. I'm trying to make it work on a table with many results with diffrent Ids.

like so : https://gyazo.com/9366bab83fa4401e1b88b28e27ffa55f

Controller Index Post

```
        //== Action - Index
        [Authorize(Roles = SD.Tier3User)]
        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string id)
        {
            var UserFromDb = await _db.ApplicationUser.FindAsync(id);

            if (UserFromDb.LockoutEnabled == true)
            {
                //== Lo desactiva (LockOutEnabled = 0)
                UserFromDb.LockoutEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //== Lo activa (LockOutEnabled = 1)
                UserFromDb.LockoutEnabled = true;
            }

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

HTML button

```
<td>
    @if (User.IsInRole(SD.Tier3User))
        {
          <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.User.Id" class="btn btn-sm 
           btn-outline-primary">Editar</a>

           == HERE I USE SWEET ALERT ===
           @if (item.User.LockoutEnabled)
             {
<button type="submit" onclick="CambiarEstado()" asp-route-id="@item.User.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning">Desactivar</button>
              }
              else
              {
<button type="submit" onclick="CambiarEstado()" asp-route-id="@item.User.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Re-activar</button>


              }<a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.User.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
         }
</td>
```

JS Sweet alert

```
    <script>
        function CambiarEstado() {
            document.querySelector('#Estado').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                var form = this;
                event.preventDefault();

                swal({
                    title: "¿Desea cambiar el estado de este usuario?",
                    icon: "success",
                    buttons: [
                        'No',
                        'Si'
                    ],

                }).then(function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        swal("¡Estado cambiado!", {
                            buttons: false,
                            timer: 500,
                        }).then(function () {

                            form.submit();
                        });
                    } else {
                        swal("Acción cancelada", "Recuerde que un usuario desactivado no puede entrar al sistema", "error");
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    </script>
```

It was suppose to de-activate the user, but first ask if I'm sure of that action, Instead it returns an error since the id the post event got was `null`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `asp-route-*` attribute is not valid on a `button` element. That attribute is specifically utilized by the `AnchorTagHelper` (i.e. for `a` elements). You need to either use an actual anchor tag, and simply style it as a button:

```
<a onclick="CambiarEstado()" asp-action="Foo" asp-route-id="@item.User.Id" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning">Desactivar</a>
```

Or you'll need to create a hidden input within your `form` tag to hold the id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.User.Id" />
```

Note: it's unclear what's actually happening here, so you should bear in mind that if you use the action link approach, that will not submit anything. It's a regular GET request at that point, and the `id` will be added as query param to the `href` that's generated (hence the need to also specify `asp-action`). More likely than not, you want to stick with the button and add a hidden input.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, I definetly need to stick to the  button since this is an action post and I need a submit button, I've tried the hidden input approach but it hasn't worked out, maybe i'll try it a diffrent way, If I find something I'll let you know! thanks :)

Comment: This would seem to be an XY problem then. You had one issue, decided on a way to solve *that* issue, which ended up not working either, and you asked about your decided approach instead of the actual problem you need to solve. Always ask about your *actual* issue, not some intended solution. You should revise your question with the original code that didn't work, so people can help you with *that* instead.

Comment: This is the actual issue, I only forgot to mention I also tried the hidden input, the diffrence is that without hidden input the page returns an error message, while when using the hidden input it just activates the post method with the first user on my list, I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear, It's my first time using the website. Cheers

Comment: Each button in the list will need to have it's own `form` with its own hidden input.